# simple way to see container image(s) running in a AWS ECS service in command line

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line-interface, amazon-ecs

Whats the easiest way to display the currently running container images in a ECS service from a command line? Currently I'm using an ugly mix of aws cli and jq:

`aws ecs list-services --cluster CLUSTER_NAME | jq -r '.serviceArns | .[] | select(. | contains("SERVICE_NAME"))|split("/")|last' |xargs -I {} aws ecs describe-services --cluster CLUSTER_NAME --services {}|jq -r '.services[0].taskDefinition|split("/")|last'| xargs -I {} aws ecs describe-task-definition --task-definition {}|jq '.taskDefinition.containerDefinitions[0].image'`

Surely there must be an easier way?

Comment: Instead of `jq` you can use `--query` to apply jmespath expressions. I think otherwise this solution looks fine.

Comment: I'm aware of jmespath, tried it a bit. Doesn't feel like a huge improvement on top of jq though...

Comment: Can you clarify what do you mean by "easiest"? For example, by not using jq and only `--query`? Or use bash function or alias instead of your one-liner? Or replace bash with python script for instance?

Comment: I would assume it's not an uncommon scenario and would ideally want to have a single cli tool call without chaining multiple calls to aws tool and jq extracting information from output.

something like:
`the-tool get-docker-image --cluster-name CLUSTER_NAME --service-name MY_SERVICE_NAME`

Comment: if your code already works, you can just wrap it into basic bash function that will take the  --cluster-name  and --service-name arguments.

Answer (score 3):

You can do a little better if you describe task definitions directly instead of going through services first. You can get rid of `jq` if you use `--query`. And you can get rid of `xargs` if you use a nested command.

```
aws ecs describe-tasks --output text --query 'tasks[].containers[].[image]' --tasks `aws ecs list-tasks --desired-status RUNNING --query taskArns --output text`
```

`list-tasks` supports `--cluster` if you want to limit it to just one of the clusters.

[ecs-cli](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/cmd-ecs-cli-ps.html) is a command line tool specifically made for ECS, but it doesn't print out the image, only the task definition name.

Comment: the argument for `--query` needs to be `tasks[*].containers[].image`

Comment: zsh, mac, cli 2.7.27.  I had to put single quotes around `tasks[].containers[].[image]` and `--cluster` is required for both describe-tasks and list-tasks (unless you have a cluster named `default`.

Answer (score 2):

I have just tried to simplify your given query & it works. Please give it try:

```
aws ecs describe-services \
--services SERVICE_NAME \
--cluster CLUSTER_NAME |  jq ".services[0].deployments[0].taskDefinition" | xargs -I {} aws ecs describe-task-definition --task-definition {} | jq '.taskDefinition.containerDefinitions[0].image'
```

Comment: Code only answers are not considered good practice. Please consider [Explaining how this answers the question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers)